# Relationship between the eigenvectors of $T$ and $S^{-1}TS$

Tags: linear-algebra

$T$, $S$ are linear operator on vector space $V$. What is the relationship between the eigenvectors of $T$ and $S^{-1}TS$?I know they have the same eigenvalues.Are there eigenvectors essentially the same but in different basis? I do not know how to prove it.

Comment: Yes, if $v$ is the eigvect of $V$ then $S^{-1}v$ is the eigvect. of the latter, just substitute.

Comment: I do not quite understand...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $V$ be an eigenvector of $S^{-1}TS$ associated with eigenvalue $\lambda$:

$$S^{-1}TSV=\lambda V$$

Left multiplication by $S$ gives the equivalent relationship:

$$T(SV)=\lambda SV$$

which means that $SV$ is an eigenvector of $T$ associated with eigenvalue $\lambda$.

Comment: It's poor notation to use capital letters for both vectors and operators :\

Comment: @Tony S.F. You are right, but I wouldn't call it "poor notation" but "lack of time to devote to ideal typographical conventions". But I agree that I should have placed "\mathbf" at different places...